# How to refactor thousands of lines of Java code? Is there any tool available?

Tags: java, swing, refactoring

In our application we have two or three classes which contains the entire Java Swing application logic. These two or three classes contain around 7k lines of code.

Now I have been assigned the task to refactor this Java code.

How do I start? Is there any tool available that will do the refactoring or at least guide us?

Comment: what you exactly want to do in refactoring ?

Comment: Sorry to be a black cloud, but wouldn't it be better at this stage to do a complete re-write from the ground up using good OOP techniques?

Comment: I agree but current product Java swing app is in production sites. To increase maintain ability we need to do this stuff.

Comment: The Brain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain

Comment: what´s the aim of this refactoring?

Comment: refactoring means remove couplings, create maintainable code from this file, enhance GUI etc

Comment: @Hovercraft: Ground-up rewrites are almost never a good idea. Even a mere 7 kLOC can be a minefield of hidden assumptions that you'll be relearning for the next year.

Comment: @Hovercraft, rewrites is the last resort.  Do not underestimate the amount of experience present into the existing codebase.

Comment: @u3050, which IDE do you use today?

Comment: When your talking about enhancing GUI, you're not really refactoring but adding / changing features to the code.

Comment: @u3050 : If you are going to be the poor soul that needs to maintain this code, refactoring using an IDE is a safe way to start as it allows you to refactor in small steps, in a controlled way, without introducing additional errors/bugs. Once the code is refactored enough for you to understand it better, then you can think about a partial or complete rewrite.

Comment: Whatever you end up deciding on, *please* have some unit tests available so you can ensure that you are not inadvertently changing the behavior of the system after the reorganization.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RefactorLowHangingFruit and read http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052

Comment: This sounds like an exercise in futility... were you one of the original developers of the app (so at least you understand what the app is supposed to do)? are you an experienced Java/Swing developer (that's been pulled in to improve the design of an existing app)? Or are you just a new hire whose manager said something like "You should refactor this app to scale it for the cloud and create a compelling user experience."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to break up these large classes into smaller ones.  The most common way to do this is with the [Extract Class](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) refactoring.  It just happens that this is a major topic in my PhD thesis work.

One of the hard parts is deciding what goes into the new classes.  There are two publicly available tools that I know of that help - [ExtC](http://code.google.com/p/ext-c/wiki/DocumentationExtC) (my tool) and [JDeodorant](http://java.uom.gr/~jdeodorant/).  Both are Eclipse plug-ins, and I would classify both as being prototypes.  If you want to try to use my tool, I'll be glad to help.

Once you decide what should go into the new class, you have to do the actual work of separating the class into others.  Eclipse's Extract Class refactoring is misnamed and [isn't really helpful](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312347).  IntelliJ's IDEA is much better, but still has some bugs.  JDeodorant can also perform the split, but it also has some bugs.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend Eclipse - the brilliant Java IDE for the editing and refactoring.  It has several tools for refactoring.  An excellent tutorial on how to do it with Eclipse is located at:

http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~eclipse/13-Refactoring.pdf

There's a brililant article on the power of refactoring with Eclipse, if you're not yet convinced, at:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html

And finally another article on how to refactor in Eclipse, including techniques and tools, is available at:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecref/

There's also another stackoverflow question on strategies for refactoring Java code that you may be interested in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128498/what-are-the-best-code-refactoring-strategies

Hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has some built-in refactoring tools. You could refactor method's signatures, extract interfaces and classes, pull methods up and down in the hierarchy tree, move packages ... and all that just by two clicks.

Also, you could start with a Martin Fowler book "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code".

Comment: *all that just by two clicks* for nicely designed, loosely coupled classes, yes. If the code is the nightmare I think it is, the eclipse refactoring tools don't really stand a chance.

Comment: I agree code is nightmare and I need to refactor, redesing it in a way so that it is maintainable

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has all the smarts for understanding Java code and provides excellent refactorings. And now there is a [free and open source version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html).

Comment: The 30-trial version should allow quite a bit of work to be done.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, IntelliJ refactors you :-)

Answer (score 0):

As refactoring code relies primarily on the developer (assisted by tooling), your IDE is a very important tool when it comes to refactoring.

Both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA have plenty of refactoring support.

For an overview, checkout:

- http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/refactoring.html
- http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-refactoring.htm

Comment: If code is loose coupled and already follows OOP then we can go for Eclipse refactoring it will be easy to refactor. But as in my case its 7k lines without using any MVC, OOP techniques in this case how do we create refactored code?

Comment: See my comment in your question... in some cases, refactoring this type of code using baby-steps (refactoring steps provided by the IDE) will lead to code that will give you more insight in what it is doing...  A next step can be to do a partial re-write / re-structuring that goes beyond the std refactorings offered by the IDE. But you need a starting point, as re-writing from scratch is rarely done (based on my experience in software development at least)

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own refactoring tool that tries and group together methods that use the same set of variables. It is very much an early prototype. It is only available as a Windows Eclipse plugin.

[Variable Usage Eclipse Plugin](http://www.willcodejavaforfood.com/vu.html)