# Struggling to refactor a Player class with more than 4000 LOC

Tags: refactoring

Here is the situation:
I'm implementing a 4-players card game. It has a lot of different rules and requires some real intelligence to be played. So I started designing the abstract types such as Card and Player and the relationships between them, and then I started defining the interfaces and so on ..

The only class I'm struggling to refactor is the Player class. I've defined a simple interface for this class that has 9 methods (e.g play(), takeCard(Card), etc..) So I got started by implementing these methods, and then the problem began ...

I used a lot of logic and private methods (such as canCardEat(), doesTeamMateHaveCard(Card) etc.) in order to make the player as smart as possible. When I finished writing the first working version of the class, the player was pretty intelligent in his plays, BUT, I've found that there was more than 5000 lines of code, and exactly 187 private methods, only in this class! :(

I am now horrified by these numbers, so I tried to eliminate and merge some of the private methods until I reached a total of 4500 LOC and about 160 (private) methods. Still, a huge class.

I did search for a solution and all I got was "split the class into multiple classes". The problem is that I couldn't. I thought of creating a LogicalBrain class and use an instance of it as an instance variable in the Player class, so the player instance would then ask the logical brain to do the work. But then the problem will remain because I will have to move about 90% of the code in Player into the new class.

So my questions are:

1. If you were me, what would you do to refactor the Player class?
2. Is there another technique to implement the intelligence that suits my situation other than logic-based code and ANN?

Comment: Does your code work as it is? Is there some real reason why you need to do this, or is it just gold-plating at this point?

Comment: @Jim, Yes, it works perfectly. The reason why I want to refactor is to make the class as comprehensible as possible. Because of the current huge number of methods, it takes me a while until I find the one I need. And sometimes I even create a duplicate method because I "forgot" that it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333452/how-to-refactor-thousands-of-lines-of-java-code-is-there-any-tool-available/4341135#4341135).  There are a couple of tools available that can help, if your code is in Java.  One thing to look for is clusters of methods that use each other and a subset of the attributes.  These clusters can be used as the basis for new classes.

Comment: Thanks kc2001. I followed your suggestion, and thankfully I've found many methods that take a collection of cards and return some result. I'm moving them out now to a new class. And I'll keep looking for more of these clusters. Thanks.