# Separation of code to different classes [Java]

Tags: java, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have a bloated JDialog class (~2000 lines) that displays two unrelated JTables. I want to split it into three classes (JDialog, Jtable1 and JTable2). I can study which variables and which methods are used by each table and move them to relevant classes, but this manual refactoring is going to be tedious.

Is there any way to automate such refactoring?

---

To achieve this a script should have an accumulator of tokens. First token is, for instance `jTable2` from panel.add(jTable2). Now check all lines that have jTable2 in them and add tokens to accumulator. Repeat search for relevant tokens until new tokens are not discovered. Now for each token find lines that contain it. Expand selection to include brackets.

It is hard to believe that programmers of the arguably largest language haven't created such a tool yet. This should be pretty similar to find usages tool in IDE.

Comment: "Arguably largest language" - I thought this was a fine question until I read that addition.  I don't think you understand how refactoring is done.  How many of the other languages have done such a thing?  My guess is "none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NetBeans you can use Refactor->move. It starts a wizard that conveniently displays relevant methods. You need to select them that you want to move, but you don't have to hunt in code. Other IDEs have similar functionality.

This way you still have to think, but the boring part of finding them is done for you by IDE.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thinking is fun, extracting all possibly relevant lines of code is not. Good to know that refactor -> move is this smart.

Comment: "Other IDEs have similar functionality" - including IntelliJ.  There's nothing automatic about it.

Answer (score 6):

Automatic?  No, thank goodness.  Refactoring requires thought.  Deep learning isn't there yet.

Most IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ from JetBrains, the best IDE on the market) has excellent refactoring support.

But it won't think for you.

One piece of advice: You'll have better luck if you have unit tests, do it in small incremental bites, and use a version control system.  Write a test, make a change, show that the test still passes, commit the change, repeat.

You can always go back to the last working version that way.  You won't make a bigger mess than a single incremental step.

I think you can do even better: look at moving listeners and processing code out of the UI, too.  Swing apps end up with big classes because people learn to cram everything into the UI classes.  If you decompose it you'll find that the code is easier to read, more modular, and easier to unit test.

Comment: Excellent choice.  I'm sure you'll do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post ([How to refactor thousands of lines of Java code? Is there any tool available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333452/how-to-refactor-thousands-of-lines-of-java-code-is-there-any-tool-available)) that asks a similar question.

Basically, there are some production quality tools that help you extract classes once you know what it is what you want to put in the classes.  Notably, IntelliJ's IDEA has a good "extract class" refactoring.

The harder part is determining what should go into those classes.  AFAIK, there are only research tools available for that.